# WebGL - initGL is not defined

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I was trying a tutorial which would draw a triangle and a square using WebGL.
http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28 that one.

So when I got to the first testing zone.
I got the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initGL is not defined.

This is my code:

```
var triangleVertexPositionBuffer;
var squareVertexPositionBuffer;

function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson01-canvas");
    initGL(document.getElementById("lesson01-canvas"));
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    drawScene();
}

function initBuffers() {
    // driehoek
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    var vertices = [
         0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 3;

    // vierkant
    squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    vertices = [
         1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 4;
}

function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);
    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,      
            triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [3.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,
            squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Those functions (e.g. `initGL`) are *not* part of [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL)

Presumably they are other functions in (or which should have been mentioned by) the tutorial - maybe there is a JavaScript library that should be included? It appears that `initGL` should also have set the global `gl` variable.

For instance, see ["initGL"](http://learningwebgl.com/cookbook/index.php/How_to_initialise_WebGL) of the same site (which I found by searching for "WebGL initGL"). You'll have to hunt down the other definitions (where is `initShaders`?) to patch the given code ..

Answer (score 2):

Like user2864740 mentioned you are missing some helper functions that the tutorial writer has created. I would suggest clicking the "*Click here and you’ll see the live WebGL version*" link near the top of every chapter and viewing the source code.

It seems you are missing the following code:

```
var gl;
function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
}


function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}


var shaderProgram;

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
}


var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
}
```

Depending on the rest of the html on your page, you may also be missing the following script tags:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
</script>
```